# Write to Samba fails for only one application

Tags: linux, windows, samba

A samba server was setup on a Centos 6.4 box with SELinux unenforced.
It's configured and running, and from Windows with it mapped to a network drive most users and applications can read and execute them. I can make new documents, save from MS Office, open, and delete, all from the same login with the samba mapped to Z:\ on the Windows machine. What I cannot do is save from DreamSpark PCB run on the same machine for reasons that escape me.

The permissions for the designsparktest/onemorelevel/ is are 0770, its group is wheel, recursively. Every user is in wheel.

Here's the relevant bits of smb.conf:

```
[global]

acl check permissions = no

#============================ Share Definitions ==============================

[working]
    comment = 'working' directory
    path = /misc/working
    writeable = yes
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    inherit permissions = yes
    create mode = 0770
    directory mode = 0770
    valid users = blake randy jeffg ccchen andrew jlumish ivanh bobbief michal denzel pawel przemek jpcaram jreeves thchen darek adam wguest
```

Here's a snippet of the error that occurs from smbd.log, set to level 3 so there's a lot of similar stuff.  Ask me and I'll grep through it for you.

```
[2014/02/05 11:54:32, 3] smbd/process.c:process_smb(1101)
  Transaction 349 of length 172
[2014/02/05 11:54:32, 3] smbd/process.c:switch_message(932)
  switch message SMBtrans2 (pid 10747) conn 0x2ba0f70d7420
[2014/02/05 11:54:32, 3] smbd/trans2.c:call_trans2qfilepathinfo(3314)
  call_trans2qfilepathinfo: TRANSACT2_QPATHINFO: level = 1004
[2014/02/05 11:54:32, 3] smbd/vfs.c:reduce_name(821)
  reduce_name [designsparktest/onemorelevel/TestBoardPCB.sch] [/misc/working]
[2014/02/05 11:54:32, 3] smbd/vfs.c:reduce_name(922)
  reduce_name: designsparktest/onemorelevel/TestBoardPCB.sch reduced to /misc/working/designsparktest/onemorelevel/TestBoardPCB.sch
[2014/02/05 11:54:32, 3] smbd/trans2.c:call_trans2qfilepathinfo(3350)
  call_trans2qfilepathinfo: SMB_VFS_STAT of designsparktest/onemorelevel/TestBoardPCB.sch failed (No such file or directory)
```

I've seen similar questions in response to that last line about not being able to create new files but they always apply across the board. This user has demonstrated that it has permissions and can create files. It's just this one application that I've encountered where he cannot save to the shared Samba.